# Invalid Host header - Unable to connect to my application hosted on droplet in digital ocean with domain name in url but works with ip address

Tags: angular, digital-ocean, namecheap

I am unable to get my domain name connected to my droplet which is hosting an angular 2 application. I am able to ping the domain name and see the reply with proper ip address in it. I am also able to open the application with ip address like http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:4200 but trying with my domain name like http://example.com:4200 returns error -

```
This site can’t be reached
refused to connect.
```

If I try http://example.com, get error -

```
This www.example.com page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://www.example.com/
```

Application is running on port 4200. Port 4200, 8080, 80, 443 have access on to them.
When I tried to run the application on port 80 to see if that has anything to do with it, it works with ip by hitting http://xxx.xxx.xx.x (without port) but gives error with http://example.com

```
Invalid Host header
```

Have searched many tutorials, but no help.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you ping your domain?

Comment: @Juan , I was able to. But to my surprise, its returning a different ip (incorrect) on my pc now and different one (correct ip) on another pc. Weird.

Comment: Are you overriding the ip adress in the hosts file of your computer?

Comment: Nopes. Infact, it was working and returning correct ip till some time before. Two different ips is what not making sense to me.

Comment: Can you confirm the problem is with your machine by reaching the application from a different computer?

Comment: Yes, its something with my machine. Issue remains same as in question. One can ping it (domain name) and gets the correct ip of droplet.

Comment: If the ping from your machine to a domain is going to a different ip, it is a domain resolution issue. It can be as I said before in that you have that hostname pointing to a different ip in the hosts file, or it could be the DNS you use, or also a proxy could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It was `--disable-host-check` which I was overlooking for some reason which worked for me. Not sure how to deal with it in a proper way. Need more homework.